# Android: switch to a new fragment inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an Android application with a `MainActivity` and I do this to create navigational tabs in `onCreate`:

```
ActionBar myActionBar = getActionBar();
myActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
Tab tab = myActionBar.newTab().setText("FirstTab").setIcon(R.drawable.first_tab)
    .setTabListener(new TabListener<FirstTabFragment>(this, "FirstTab", 
    FirstTabFragment.class));
... more tabs ...
```

The `TabListener`, I use this from developer.android.com:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#newTab():

```
public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    ...
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) { ... }
}
```

So if a user clicks on the first tab, my fragment `FirstTabFragment` is called and executes  `onCreateView`.

My problem is, if a user now clicks a button I do the following and I do not know how to switch to the next fragment:

```
private OnClickListener firstTabListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == button1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(???, MyDetailsFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (...) {
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

The `MyDetailsFragment`should show details to the selected item (button click), so I want to drill down to the details fragment and want to give some extra data to the new fragment, so the detail fragment knows which details of which selected item it should display.
The selected tab should not change and the back button should go back to the FirstTabFragment page.

I think I should start a new fragment, but it is not possible, the name of the method `startActivity` tells me that I start a new activity and not a fragment. So, I have to use the `MainActivity` and put into there the new fragment?
(I do not use the android-support-v4.jar library, because I only target Android 4 devices)

How can I solve this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fragment, call a method on the hosting activity, telling it about the button click event. The activity can then do whatever is appropriate.

Personally, I think that totally replacing the contents of a tab is inappropriate in the vast majority of cases, but you are certainly welcome to do it.

Comment: I have a list of items with image and text. If a user clicks on one of them, the user should see the details of the selected item, so I think it should be okay?! What about this solution: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); MyDetailsFragment frag = new MyDetailsFragment(); fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, frag); fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: @Tim: "so I think it should be okay?" -- not from inside a tab, IMHO. But that is my personal UX preference, not a statement of what is technically possible or not. That being said, using `addToBackStack()` here is a *really* bad idea, as if the user is on another tab, and they press BACK, they will not see any change, and will think that your app is broken. If *you* wish to have an unconventional UI approach like navigation within tabs, *you* will have to write the BACK handling yourself.

Comment: Okay, I am not very experienced in Android development, I only developed iOS apps, and there is no back button only inside of a tab. So, I have still to learn :-) But I am happy that I can switch fragments, the back handler, I will take a look later, because I have so many new concepts which I have to realize. Thanks.

Comment: I handled it with the back stack, so a user will really have the back-button feeling. Every click on the back button the user will see previous screen (if necessary automatically switching the tab). With your answer you are totally right. I see the "best practices" and normally the activity should handle the switching/replacing of fragments. I will change this in near future. Thank you for your help!